# Google Sheets MATCH string and return OFFSET 2 columns to the right

Tags: google-sheets, match, google-sheets-formula, offset, array-formulas

I have 2 worksheets in a single google sheet file. I need to take the value of a cell in Worksheet2, find it in Worksheet1 get the offset of that matched value 2 columns to the right, and return that string value to the cell in worksheet2.

This is the closest I've been able to get but concat always changes it to a string not a value and offset wont work with it.

```
=OFFSET(CONCAT("'Worksheet1'!A",MATCH(B4,'Worksheet1'!A:A)),0,2)
```

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 1):

try:

```
=VLOOKUP(B4, 'Worksheet1'!A:C, 3, 0)
```

or AF:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(B4:B, 'Worksheet1'!A:C, 3, 0)))
```